# upgrade .Net5.0 to .Net 6.0 ,

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

While I am trying to update .Net5.0 to Net6.0, I Have This Issue

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITypeBase.get_ClrType()'.

How I Can Fix it?

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ITypeBase.get_ClrType()'.

Comment: This is a known breaking change (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes#ireadonly-metadata). As a workaround you can invoke these methods through reflection.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26701 might be of interest.

Comment: where excatly i can find IModel?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update the nuget packages and if they are no longer available find an alternative.

Comment: I Already Did that, But as well as I'm Using Asp.Net Boilerplate , I cannot Run it, The Browser Give Me 500 Error,